# Maximum rate of heat transfer in a balanced counter flow heat exchanger in NTU method

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer, heat-exchanger

In effectiveness NTU method for heat exchangers, we have effectiveness of the heat exchanger defined as

$$\epsilon = \frac{Q_{actual}}{Q_{max}}$$

Where $$Q_{max} $$ is the maximum rate of heat transfer in a counter flow heat exchanger with some prescribed inlet temperature and heat capacity rates.

$$\text{when}\begin{cases}
C_H< C_C, & \dot{Q}_{max} = C_H(T_{h,i}- T_{c,i})\\
C_C< C_H, & \dot{Q}_{max} = C_C(T_{h,i}- T_{c,i})\\
\end{cases} $$

What will be the maximum rate of heat transfer that will be taken when heat exchanger is balanced i.e. $$C_h = C_c $$

Comment: O dear. When C_h = C_c then C_h*(T_hi-T_ci)=C_c(T_hi-T_ci) ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the length of the heat exchanger.

generally, in the steady state there will be an steady temperature difference across the length of the heat exchanger. The difference will be smaller for higher lengths.

If the length is long enough, then eventually:

- the out temperature of the hot $t_{h,o}$ will be equal to the inlet of the cool $t_{c,i}$
- the out temperature of the cold $t_{c,o}$ will be equal to the inlet of the hot $t_{h,i}$

[image]

**Figure : counter flow heat exchanger with 6000 m ( 3kg/s mass rate of water, cool:400K, hot:800, initial condition 300K )**

[image]

**Figure : counter flow heat exchanger with 60 m ( 3kg/s mass rate of water, cool:400K, hot:800, initial condition 300K )**

Comment: If we consider long enough length case then in a counter flow heat exchanger with heat capacity rates equal, the temperature profiles become linear and parallel. So, if at any length Th,o=Tc,i and Tc,o=Th,i then wouldnt the temperature profiles of the hot and cold fluids coincide? in which case the heat transfer will stop?

Comment: @HarshitRajput heat transfer doesn't stop, you just can't get any more out of the system because heat only flows from hot to cold.

Comment: I have edited in the question what I want to say, that as we keep on increasing the length the temperature profiles of the hot and cold fluids will approach each other and then finally coincide

Comment: That's what I've been trying to say all along, that if the length is loooong enough and the flow characteristics are equal then the temperatures will eventually be reversed.

Comment: Oh okay so the temperatures profiles will coincide right at long enough length?

Comment: So won't the heat transfer be zero when temperature profiles coincide? Like at any x if we consider the temperature of the hot and cold fluids will be the same, so no temperature difference and no heat transfer. Which is somewhat contradicting the fact that fluids are entering the leaving at different tempature so they have gained and lost energy

Comment: Assuming you can reach the steady state, the temperature difference will be inversely proportional to the length of the heat exchanger. So it will *asymptotically* reach zero. So what will happen is that **in the steady state** (however long it takes), the temperature difference will be so small so that the heat exchange is *spread out* in the length of the exchanger.  The point of the images I put, is that if the length changes too much, then there is a very very long transiet period.

Comment: Oh I somewhat understand now. Could you please tell me the software you used for the simulations?

Comment: I modified a code from Kody Powell's [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEdP9WH_Q3c) and I adapted the code for a counter flow exchanger.

Answer (score 0):

When the two heat capacities are the same, then Hot out = cold in, the same as the CH < CC.  You can't get more heat out of the hot side than the delta between the hot entering temp and the cold entering temp, so this max occurs for all conditions where the cold side heat capacity is equal to or greater than the hot side.